AppleScript file renaming folder action script errors out
I sought to create an AppleScript folder action to rename files added to a folder by giving them a warning prefix if they lack a double space and three space prefix if they lack spaces altogether. I took care to make those prefixes contain double spaces so as to avoid the looping that occurs due to AppleScript treating a file rename as a new file addition (although it would be unspeakably useful if any of you had a workaround for that) but the script errors out on multiple lines, and since it is a folder action I can only test it by installing it and dragging items into the folder so I cannot see logs on why that is. However, through trial and error I have been able to check line by line and know all the lines not specifically called out as erroring out work fine in isolation.
For those willing to help out (be it with help with this code or alternative solutions to achieve my ultimate goal) you are much appreciated. Here is the code:
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving themItems
    tell application "Finder"
        
        -- Loop through the newly detected items
        repeat with anItem in themItems
            
            set filename to name of anItem
            
            if filename does not contain "  " then
                
                --Display the folder name (tried for testing, errors out)
                set theDialogText to "The folder name is " & name of theAttachedFolder & "."
                display dialog theDialogText
                
                -- Move the file to other folder
                move anItem to [folder path redacted for obvious reasons]
                
                -- Add the checking tag if the name contains a space, if it doesn't add triple spaces
                --(the ifs work but the instructions error out)
                if filename contains " " then set name of anItem to ",tocheck  " & filename
                if filename does not contain " " then set name of anItem to "   " & filename
                
                -- Move the file back (this errors out)
                move anItem to theFolder
                
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    
end adding folder items to


Note that renaming or moving the item back into the watched folder will trigger the folder action again.

@red_menace I did note that in crafting the code (the tags contain double spaces meaning the renamed file will fail the first condition) and in the answer itself, but thanks for the tip

AppleScript tip: if it doesn't work then add (). Try set theDialogText to "The folder name is " & (name of theFolder) & ".".

Another tip: when you move anItem to another folder then anItem still points to the item before it was moved. move returns the object after it was moved. Changing the name also makes anItem invalid. Why do you move the file to a folder and back?

What errors? Please include what happens, ie the error message. They have meaning. Also don't redact information. Nobody expects you to post revealing or confidential information. Instead, make a folder on the desktop and work with that, or just include a generic, non-existing path. One of your 'errors out' is because you have yet to declare what theAttachedFolder is. It looks like you are trying to use a drop folder as a place of storage? Why? Use it solely as a staging area and have your final storage outside of it. Then you won't need to worry about spaces.

To answer to @Willeke 's question, I move the file because renaming a file inside a folder triggers the Folder Action again and creates an endless loop. I have tried preventing it by only altering the name upon conditions that an edited name will not fulfill, but somehow those 'if's were circumvented and the edit kept getting repeated over and over despite the resulting filename not getting edited if dropped in the folder as it was. I will look into the parentheses.

To answer @Mockman , I thought from the reference material I'd consulted that TheAttachedFolder would be the name of the folder to which the folder action was attached. Nevertheless, I will try defining variables manually and see if that solves things and thank you for the tip. As for why I wish to have the pictures themselves end up where they are dropped, that is because the same folder would be the one to both save the files in question to and retrieve them from, which would marginally speed up and simplify file managing.
